# Why does my variable change after strtok() and fgets() without modifying it?

Tags: c, file, text, undefined-behavior, c-strings

Demonstration of the problem here: http://goo.gl/71U1xA

I am reading a file, and in that file there is a line:

```
SECTIE FIELD_IN #define ENDSEC
```

that indicates I need to store the lines following this one to a variable, but **only** if the line contains the part "`#define`".

So, I'm iterating trough the file and when the line contains "`SECTIE`" and "`FIELD_IN`", it retrieves the word with `#` in it and it stores it in the variable `keyWord`.

Now the problem is: the value in `keyWord` changes in the next loop without modifying it.

My textfile is:

```
SECTIE FIELD_IN1 #define ENDSEC
#define COL1                1,1
#define COL2                2,3
#define COL3                5,3
...etc
```

And the output of my code is this:

> ```
> START
>
> reading line
> text=SECTIE FIELD_IN1 #define ENDSEC
>
> keyword1=..
> new sectie
> keyword2=.#define.
>
> reading line
> text=#define COL1              1,1
>
> keyword1=.            1,1
> .
> start = 1!
> keyword3=.            1,1
> .
> ```

My code:

```
int     x, status, start;
char    inputLine[5000 + 1];
char    copyLine[5000 + 1];
char    *keyWord = "";
FILE    *iFile;

status  = NOERROR;
x       = 0;
start   = 0;

iFile = fopen(gsz_inputFile, "r");  
if(iFile == NULL){ 
    status = ER_OPEN;
    return status;
}

while (fgets(inputLine, sizeof(inputLine), iFile) != NULL){

    printf("\n\nreading line");

    printf("\ntext=%s", inputLine);

    printf("\nkeyword1=.%s.", keyWord);

    strcpy(copyLine, inputLine);
    strlwr(copyLine);
    if(strstr(copyLine, "sectie") != NULL && strstr(copyLine, "field_in") != NULL){
        start = 1;

        printf("\nnew sectie");

        //get keyword
        keyWord = strtok(inputLine," ");
        while (keyWord != NULL)
        {
            if(strstr(keyWord, "#") != NULL){               
                break;
            }

            keyWord = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }

        printf("\nkeyword2=.%s.", keyWord); //here the keyword is correct
        continue;
    }

    if(start){
        printf("\nstart = 1!");

        printf("\nkeyword3=.%s.", keyWord);

        //status = storeString(inputLine, keyw, x); //my actual code is different
        if(status != NOERROR){ x--; }

        x++;
    }       
}
```

I think it has something to do with `while (fgets(inputLine, sizeof(inputLine), iFile) != NULL)` because after that line is executed, the value is changed.

Why is the value of `keyWord` changed after going into the next loop? My guess it has to do with undefined behavior, but I can't put my finger on the problem.

Comment: Do you know how pointers work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `inputLine` which is an array. Inside it you store the string fetched by `fgets()`:

```
while (fgets(inputLine, sizeof(inputLine), iFile) != NULL){
```

And in your loop you say `keyWord` points to some inputLine's token (which means it points to somewhere inside your array).

```
//get keyword
keyWord = strtok(inputLine," ");
```

When you run the second `fgets()` the array content's change, but not its address, so keyWord still points to inputLine content's *which have changed*

Example:

```
first fgets():
inputLine: ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
keyWord-->""
second strtok:
keyWord------------------------------------^

second fgets():
inputLine: ['T', 'h', 'i', 's', ' ', 'c', 'h', 'a', 'n', 'g', 'e']
keyword------------------------------------^ (before strtok)
```

You assumption "*The value of* `keyWord` changed" is false: The value of keyword is still the same, you can check it with `printf("value of keyWord: %p\n", keyWord);`. What changed is the value `keyWord`*points to*, which is what you display using `%s` in printf.

Answer (score 3):

`strtok` modifies the input buffer. So the `keyword` you get at the end of the loop is a pointer to location within the `inputLine`. When the loop reads another line using `fgets` it gets overwritten.